# Remove Excel column formatting while data import in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, formatting

I have an Excel file which has a custom format applied on a decimal column. The custom format doesn't have any decimal places but I actually need "as-is" data with decimal places and save it in DB using SSIS excel source.

Currently, the excel source previews data with no decimal and loads data with formatting. I need the excel source to get non-formatted data.

PS: Modifying Excel file is not an option for me as these files comes daily from a different source and I have a stack of 1000+ back dated files to load into the database.

Can we remove Excel column formatting in SSIS script task?

Here is an example of the problem: I have a column having custom format and values shown as 4,300. The actual value is 4300.2457. While using Excel source to import this data. The Excel source is importing the value as 4,300 instead of 4300.2457.

Comment: Can you give an example what behavior you are seeing now, and what you want it to be instead?

Comment: I have a column having custom format and values shown as 4,300. The actual value is 4300.2457. While using excel source to import this data. The excel source is importing the value as 4,300 instead of 4300.2457.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Data Conversion component.

You can use the excel column as it is.

Then after that you put the component and you can select which data type you want for that column.

Comment: The data conversion task comes after excel source task. The data is already trimmed by the time I can implement Data Conversion task.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Excel source and go into the advanced editor.

Go to the output columns, find the column that is having the problem, and change its DTS datatype to a decimal type.   Give it the desired precision as well.

Comment: Tried it but that's not gonna work because the excel source is not bringing original values from the excel. Instead, it is loading formatted value which has no decimal places at all.

Comment: How do you know that's what it's loading from the source?   What are you seeing that indicates that?

Comment: I can see in the preview window that the data loaded don't have decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually had to use script task to manually import excel data via OLEBDB connection. It ensures importing original values from cells.